# Angular Timer not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-timer

I want to display a count down timer.I have been referring the following page
http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/

But i am getting the below error.

> Error: Invalid isolate scope definition for directive timer: @?

Could anybody tell me what i am i missing out.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-timer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<timer end-time="1451628000000">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var appModule=angular.module('app', ['timer']);
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 13):

Try this. It's working:

I added [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [humanizeDuration.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/humanize-duration) libraries based on errors I was getting.

Hope it helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
   <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js/master/humanize-duration.js"></script>
   <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/siddii/angular-timer/master/dist/angular-timer.js"></script>
  </head>

   <body ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      <timer end-time="1451628000000">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>
 </div>
 
 <script>
    var app = angular.module('app',['timer']);
   
    app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){});
 </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I upgraded angular to AngularJS v1.1.4 and included  moment.js and humanize.js.Timer is getting displayed now but the timer is not  ticking.The timer is getting changed only when i refresh the page

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you try the above working HTML code as is? Try also with Angular 1.3.1

Comment: @JcDenton86   how can i use my Controller scopes instead of Isolated Scope ?

Comment: @N.V.Prasad, is this a new question (in your comment)? Does my answer solved your problem?

Comment: @JcDenton86  Actually it  served the Cause in Little Different way i tried to used Scope from the controller which is not Possible so u just Converted the time into  Seconds like Your answer it Works Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull in the right libraries in order for the timer to work.

```
bower install momentjs --save
bower install humanize-duration --save
```

Now in your HTML add the dependencies

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/humanize-duration/humanize-duration.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/momentjs/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```